# ms access extra table indexes

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am working on code to help me document my project. I ran some code to get the indexes from the tabledef but the results included extra indexes. Can someone explain these?

```
index: dim_daoddim_station_header
index: dim_daoddim_station_header1
index: dim_gravity_center_headerdim_station_header
index: dim_gravity_center_headerdim_station_header1
index: idx_daod_id
index: idx_gravity_center_daod
index: idx_gravity_center_header_id
index: pk_station_header_id
```

This is a many-to-many table. The bottom 4 idx are specifically designated on the table. I don't know where the first four come from.

Is this an indication I am using indexes incorrectly? Only one station header can be in this table and only one combination of gravity center and daod can be in this table.

Comment: If you create/define _referential integrity_ between tables, Access automatically create the necessary index even if a similar index already exists. Further, this new index is marked as hidden. But the names you list indicate that the source is another, indeed as they appear twofold.

Comment: @Gustav Referential integrity is established. The top four index are probably hidden because they do not show up in the GUI for the table. However, if what you say is correct, does this mean I somehow established the same integrity rules twice?

Comment: Hard to tell. But if used by RI, Access barks if you try to delete them as the index name is a part of the RI specification. You could experiment on a copy.

Comment: Maybe a compact operation will make them go away?